# Drupal 6 Faceted Search

Tags: drupal-6, faceted-search

I've been playing around with faceted search and the available display styles and wanted to know if there's a way I can write a custom display within my custom module and expose it to the list of display styles when configuring an environment.

I used the view option but the views doesn't quite produce the results I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider overriding the search related template files e.g. `search-result.tpl.php search-results.tpl.php`

Also you can use the display suite module to create a customize search result page. Check out http://drupal.org/project/ds -- there are lots of resources available.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is part of what I'm after but not entirely.  I've actually managed to implement my own display after investigating the faceted search module and the way in which it provides views as an option for display styles.